# Pandas merge with dtype=list

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `DataFrame`:

**df1:**

```
    A        B        C
0   1       [a]       x
1   2    [0, 1]       y
2   2    [0, 2]       z
```

**df2:**

```
       A        D
0      1     None
1      2     [1, 2]
```

I want to merge them based on `A` as below:

```
df = pandas.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='A')
```

Such that the result is

```
    A        B        C      D
0   1       [a]       x    None
1   2    [0, 1]       y    [1, 2]
2   2    [0, 2]       z    [1, 2]
```

However, because the dtype of column D is list, which is not hashable, I can not do it.
Could you please show me how to tackle this problem?

Comment: This works for me using Pandas 1.1.3. Nothing special required. Please include the version of Pandas you are using.

Comment: I got this error: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: @SamC: I'm using panda 1.0.1

Comment: @ManlaiA: I mean each element of column D is either NaN or list

Comment: I'm using pandas 1.2.4 and I had no problems with this either

Comment: `list` **is not a `dtype`**. This is *very important to uinderstand*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works with Python 1.3.4:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 2], 'B': [['a'], [0, 1], [0, 2]], 'C': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'D': [None, [1, 2]]})

out = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='A')
print(out)

# Output:
   A       B  C       D
0  1     [a]  x    None
1  2  [0, 1]  y  [1, 2]
2  2  [0, 2]  z  [1, 2]
```

**Update your version of Pandas**

Answer (score 0):

From what we can tell, you are incorrect. `D` doesn't need to be hashable because it's not used to determine any part of the merging. It's just copied along *after* the merging is done.

```
>>> df1
   A       B  C
0  1     [a]  x
1  2  [0, 1]  y
2  2  [0, 2]  z

>>> df1.to_numpy()
array([[1, list(['a']), 'x'],
       [2, list([0, 1]), 'y'],
       [2, list([0, 2]), 'z']], dtype=object)

>>> df2
   A       D
0  1    None
1  2  [1, 2]

>>> df2.to_numpy()
array([[1, None],
       [2, list([1, 2])]], dtype=object)

>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='A')
   A       B  C       D
0  1     [a]  x    None
1  2  [0, 1]  y  [1, 2]
2  2  [0, 2]  z  [1, 2]

>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='A').to_numpy()
array([[1, list(['a']), 'x', None],
       [2, list([0, 1]), 'y', list([1, 2])],
       [2, list([0, 2]), 'z', list([1, 2])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Oh, actually I did pd.merge(....)..drop_duplicates().
The error is in the .drop_duplicates() function.
Thank you for your help!